# How do I search for a part of a string in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create search for one of my sqlite3 tables. With a combination of a text-field or pull-down, the search should start after 3 letters have been entered and should return some recommendations which it found in the table. That's the idea at least.

For now I'm stuck at searching for a part of a string in the database.

```
"SELECT * FROM album WHERE artist='Audiosl'"
```

That does return a empty search as well as

```
"SELECT * FROM album WHERE artist LIKE 'Audiosl'"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: if there is enough memory then [`trie` or `suffixtree` might be faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5479374/4279) for an implementation of autocomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"SELECT * FROM album WHERE artist LIKE '%Audiosl%'"` would do your task.

This searches for string like `T Audiosl`, `Audiosl23`, `T Audiosl23`, etc.

Refer for more : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look into using the [`LIKE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) SQLite operator.  This would turn your statement into the following:

```
SELECT * FROM album WHERE artist LIKE 'Aud%'"
```

The `%` matches on zero or more characters.  There are more operators in the SQLite documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite includes an official [full text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) extension which provides functionality suitable for lots of text fields as your schema implies.  You can do field style searches (`artist:*a* album:"greatest hits") plus all the other stuff you would expect (NEAR, AND, OR, exclusions).`

I strongly recommend you use this extension instead of building your own queries.