# How to get both key and values in suffixtree.substringdict

Tags: python, suffix-tree

I am using [suffixtree](https://www.hashcollision.org/hkn/python/suffix_trees/) to retrive matched substring. The `readme` file contains an example as --

```
>>> import SuffixTree.SubstringDict
>>> d = SubstringDict.SubstringDict()
>>> d['foobar'] = 1  
>>> d['barfoo'] = 2
>>> d['forget'] = 3
>>> d['oo']
[1, 2]
```

The query returns values of all the strings matched with`oo`. But I didn't find any way to retrieve values as well. For example I want the result of the kind --

```
>>> d['oo']
[['foobar', 1],
 ['barfoo', 2]]
```

This class contains only the methods `['__doc__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__module__', '__setitem__', '_addToTree', '_lookupKeys', 'debug']`, and I could not used that to reach my desired output.
I found an alternate solution to get my required result, which I got the idea from the method `_dictWordsTree()` in the source file. I have rewritten the code as --

```
>>> import SuffixTree.SubstringDict
>>> d = SubstringDict.SubstringDict()
>>> d['foobar'] = ['foobar', 1]
>>> d['barfoo'] = ['barfoo', 2]
>>> d['forget'] = ['forget', 3]
>>> d['fo']
[['foobar', 1], ['barfoo', 2], ['forget', 3]]
```

And I got the desired output.
How can I get my required output without additionally storing the key as value(I have large dataset ~20MB)?
(I searched for similar [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841303/more-efficient-way-to-look-up-dictionary-values-whose-keys-start-with-same-prefi/31841363), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434813/longest-prefix-matches-for-urls/5479374#5479374), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347078/python-library-for-generalized-suffix-trees), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996137/suffix-tree-implementation-in-python), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996137/suffix-tree-implementation-in-python) threads, but it didn't help me).